# Yammer API - Paging

Tags: api, yammer

I am trying to gather a range of messages through the rest API, and am aware that you can only retrieve 20 results at a time. I have tried incrementing a page variable, but this has no affect, and I am just getting the same results each time no matter the page number (https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?page=6). I have proceeded to use the newer_than and older_than parameters to page through the results, and it works to some extent, but it appears to be excluding records. I am using the following approach below:

Since just setting a newer_than only results in the 20 most recent records as long as they are newer than the id that is sent in the newer_than parameter, I am also setting a dynamic older_than parameter.

1. Send request with only a newer than parameter. This returns the 20 most recent records. (eg. ww.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?newer_than=235560157)
2. Extract the ID of the 20th id in the JSON, and using this to populate the older_than parameter. The result is 20 different records. (eg.ww.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?newer_than=235560157&older_than=405598096)
3. Repeat step 2 until no results are returned since the newer_than and older_than parameters will eventually overlap.

The problem is that the set of records that is returned with this method is less than the number of records that is returned for messages from the data export API. I am working under the assumption that newer message IDs are always generated with a value greater than any older messages.

Could I possibly be misunderstanding how paging through results is supposed to be implemented with the REST API?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems alright to me. Of the messages that you are missing, what pattern do you notice? Are they all on one side of your newer/older_than boundary, continuous, sprinkled through the range randomly,... ?

Comment: It appears that the values are closer to the newer side of the spectrum, however the results are randomly missing records. There does not appear to be a pattern to this. In a sample set, roughly 75 of 180 records were sporadically missing. Is it possible that there are certain types of messages that are pulled out of the data export API that are not accessible with the REST API? Or am I possible missing some parameters to pull a full set of messages?

Comment: I have also noticed that the pages stop coming after a while, and appear to be limited to about 2.5-3 months or so. Could you please confirm that you have also seen the same, or know of some limitation on the amount of historical message data that can be pulled in with the REST API?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the page parameter works only for the search API.

Secondly, the way you are trying to fetch messages will not return any comments on the messages or will return top 2 comments on any message based on the "extended" parameter. By default it returns 2 comments on every message. To get all the comments on the message you will have to get it individually message wise.

That must be causing the difference in the number of messages in the two methods mentioned.

Comment: Hi Farhaan,Thanks for your response! After looking at the Threaded field in the documentation, it appears that you are correct!

threaded=[true | extended] - threaded=true will only return the first message in each thread. This parameter is intended for apps which display message threads collapsed. threaded=extended will return the thread starter messages in order of most recently active as well as the two most recent messages, as they are viewed in the default view on the Yammer web interface.

Comment: You had mentioned that if I need to get all comments on the message I would have to get it individually? Did you have an approach in mind? Is there a way I can specify the first message in a thread and have it return ALL comments? Or is there a way to call a message specifically by ID (or in bulk by IDs)?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Farhann - The rest API endpoint returns only top two comments for any message by default. To get all the comments for a post, you have to make a separate request.

With the use of the Data Export API, all the comments along with the message (public and private) are also exported which increases the count of the number of the messages. While, the API call returns only recent 2 comments on any message by default.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply! What specific request did you have in mind to get all the comments for a post? I need to get the like and content type information from the REST API that is not available in the data export API.

Answer (score 0):

The data export includes private messages.  Private messages will not be returned by that API call.

Check if the messages you are not seeing are private messages.

Comment: Hi Kyle! Thanks for the reply. I checked on against the data that we are getting from the data export API, and am still seeing messages sparratically missing from the dataset that we are getting from the REST API, even though both the message data export fields 'in_private_group' and 'in_private_conversion' are marked as false.